# ASP.NET Core MVC link added by jQuery does not work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Project on ASP NET Core MVC 3.1, jQuery v3.5.1, Bootstrap v4.1.3.

Case - get drop down list items based on user role. Drop down component from Bootstrap 4.

What works:

1. Getting drop down items from server by ajax
2. Adding `<a>` with `asp-controller=Profile` and `asp-action=Admin` tags.

What does not work:

1. I expected such scenario - clicking drop down item and sending http request on server to get admin profile page(Profile/Admin)

jQuery code which I use to create `<a>` elements in `<div>` drop-down:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdownMenuLink').on('click', function () {
            GetDropDownMenu();
        });
    });

    function GetDropDownMenu() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Menu/GetProfileMenu",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var menuDiv = $(".dropdown-menu");
                $.each(response, function (i, element) {
                    console.log(element);
                    var controllerAndAction = element.path.split('/');
                    var aElement = $('<a>').attr({ 'asp-controller': controllerAndAction[0], 'asp-action': controllerAndAction[1], 'class':"dropdown-item" });
                    aElement.text(element.text);
                    menuDiv.append(aElement);
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Html drop down element:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       Profile
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can set the asp-* properties after rendering like that.

Instead just set the href attribute of the link.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropdownMenuLink').on('click', function () {
            GetDropDownMenu();
        });
    });

    function GetDropDownMenu() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Menu/GetProfileMenu",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var menuDiv = $(".dropdown-menu");
                $.each(response, function (i, element) {
                    console.log(element);
                    var controllerAndAction = element.path.split('/');
                    //set href however you want
                    var aElement = $('<a>').attr({ 'href': "/" + controllerAndAction[0] + "/"+ controllerAndAction[1], 'class':"dropdown-item" });
                    aElement.text(element.text);
                    menuDiv.append(aElement);
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It seems it is no another way to make it works. Thank you for answer! @RobSmitha

Comment: Glad to help. ASP.NET Core MVC uses razor for html rendering ,which is done on the server side. By the time the javascript runs, you're on the client side and the asp-* tags don't go through the razor html rendering again.